# Angularjs ui-view source code

Tags: google-app-engine, angularjs, uiview, xhtml

I have an app with angularjs + gae (Java). In my index.html, I have an UI-view. When I show source code from index.html, it's ok:

```
<html>
    <head> //some contents </head>
    <body>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I go to other page, It shows the same code.

How to show other page code?

ex:  http://mysite.appspot.com/about

```
<html>
    <head> //some contents </head>
    <body>
        <div> //about html code </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the view to load from your routes.js.

ex.

```
angular.module('website', []).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/about', {templateUrl: 'about/index.html', controller: 'AboutCtrl'});
});
```

Comment: thank's for your reply. But I've already configured my routes.js like this         `$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
         templateUrl: '/pages/index.html',
            controller:[// some code ]});` and I use         `$stateProvider.state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            views: {
                '': {
                  templateUrl: '/pages/about.html',
                  controller: AboutCtrl,
                },
              },
          })`

Comment: can you help me with this way? :)

Comment: Ahh interesting. I havn't used the $stateProvider yet so I'm unsure on how to move forward structuring your routes. Sorry.

Comment: I want to make my app compatible with seo but it's not easy :(

Comment: I just bookmarked this the other day. For SEO on JS apps. http://www.brombone.com/

Comment: it's very good, but not free. I use Tukey to re-rewrite my urls but my problem is the ui-view. I can't get the html code of the curent page.

Comment: Have you tried ng-include instead? Not sure of advantages/disadvantages, I just know it exists haha

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall You can also bookmark [SEO4Ajax](http://seo4ajax.com) which is free during the beta :)